# Working with frames and Java AWT

Tags: java, layout, awt

I am currently making a program with the AWT GUI and I'm running into a problem. I basically want an image in the top left hand corner of the screen, and a column of buttons on the right of the image. This isn't what's happening though. When I run the applet, I click a popup saying "Start Program" and then the picture I want is in the applet window itself and the column of buttons is in another window by itself. This is what it looks like:

[image: screenshot]

Is there anyway to fix this so that the image and the buttons are in the same window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah.  You're creating a frame but your graphic isn't inside the frame.  Can't tell much without the code, but the [AWT Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/awt/contents.html) at java.sun.com isn't bad on this stuff.

---

Okay, a little more (I haven't used AWT in a long time.)

Here's the couple of issues you have.  A Frame is a kind of Window -- it wants to be a separate window with its own close button and so forth.

When you create your graphic, you have to tell it was component its parent is; you're somehow parenting it to the Applet.  So you have some piece of code that looks like

```
add(myComponent);
```

in the context of the Applet as `this`.

```
public class myApplet extends Applet {
   // lots of stuff here creating your canvas, putting the image in it
   // and so forth.  There's an example, see fn 1.
   // When you're done, you have a component, call it myImage.

   add(myImage);
}
```

You have a Frame, and you're adding your buttons to that.

```
public class MyFrame extends Frame {

    add(new Button(...));
    add(new Button(...));

}
```

You need to move the code that adds your Canvas into the Frame class in some method.

(WARNING: this is *not* complete Java code, I don't recall the names of the right methods offhand.  Probably the *init()* method in the Applet, at least.

fn1. http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/awt/contents.html#simpleexample

Comment: Yeah, I've followed that a little bit. It's my first time using AWT :S

Anyway, thank you and if anyone has any more suggestions, please post. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm even adding the image correctly..

This is what my main class currently looks like: 

http://friendpaste.com/61E13yV4CSR9JiFZhrDeSe

StartFrame is the frame that pops up at the beginning of the game and WindowFrame is the frame with all of the buttons on it.

Comment: Yup, there you are.  In your Applet ctor, you're creating a MediaTracker on this, then adding the graphic there.  That means you're adding the graphic to the Applet.  Here's a hint: start with a clean directory, and build a little piece on at a time.

Comment: Like, make your basic applet, put a textbox in it, make sure you an see that.  Make your Frames, and write a main method so you can run it standalone.  Try those.

Comment: Alright, I'm probably going to create an empty project and mess around with it until I understand it a little better. Thanks.

Comment: I moved the paint and update (for paint) methods into the BoardClass, which draws a lot of the other stuff. Now, the main applet is blank, which isn't a bad thing.. But the only things showing up on the WindowFrame are the buttons still. They take up all of the windowFrame.

Comment: That's probably because of the layout manager.  They're a PITA, but at least in this code, you're putting the MainWindow panel in a one-cell GridLayout, and putting your buttons in a BorderLayout.  You need to make sure you're inserting your other stuff as needed by the layout manager.